# Creating a setup file in c# which includes a sql database

Tags: c#, sql

I have created a c# windows form application using visual studio 2010, I would now like to create a setup exe file for my app, problem is, It requires a database to run, my question is how do i include this database in my setup.

I created the database using Oracle sql developer.

i am using a local connection ie. "System-XE"

Here is a code snippet of how the program communicates with the database.

```
            string oradb = "Data Source=localhost:1521/XE;User Id=system;Password=5853123;";

        OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(oradb);

        try
        {
            conn.Open();

            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();

            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT username from administrators where password = " + textBox2.Text;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            conn.Close();
            loggedIn = true;
            Close();
        }
        catch(Exception){
                MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Credentials, please try again.");
            }
        finally
        {
            if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }


        loggedIn = true;
        Close();
```

Comment: Is that your real password? Time to change then... :)

Comment: its just a university project, not actually linked to anything but.

Answer (score 1):

The most practical solution is to let the users install the database themselves and then just ask for a connection string during installation which you then put in your app.config.

It's easily done with WiX but I guess you can do it with ClickOnce as well.